# Filling a column based on multiple conditions from another columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, filtering

I'm struggling with this. I have a DataFrame like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue'],
        'B': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]}

frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And I want to create a new column based on multiple conditions from the 'A' column. For example, if 'A' is red or blue, I want this new column to be equal to 10; if 'A' is green, to be equal to 20, and so on.

The thing is, I guess I can use a nested `np.where`, but I do care about readability in here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a dictionary defining the color to numeric mapping and then use the `map` method on column A:

```
color_to_num = {'red': 10, 'blue': 10, 'green': 20, 'yellow': 30}    
frame['new'] = frame.A.map(color_to_num)

frame
#      A    B   new
#0  red     1   10
#1  green   2   20
#2  blue    1   10
#3  green   1   20
#4  yellow  2   30
#5  blue    1   10
```

Or use `replace` method:

```
frame['new'] = frame.A.replace(color_to_num)
```

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dot` because it's fun.

```
s = pd.Series({'red': 10, 'blue': 10, 'green': 20, 'yellow': 30})
frame.assign(new=pd.get_dummies(frame.A).dot(s))

        A  B  new
0     red  1   10
1   green  2   20
2    blue  1   10
3   green  1   20
4  yellow  2   30
5    blue  1   10
```

---

Or, if you really, really want `np.where`

```
a = frame.A.values
red = a == 'red'
blue = a == 'blue'
green = a == 'green'
yellow = a == 'yellow'
new = np.where(red | blue, 10, np.where(green, 20, np.where(yellow, 30, -1)))
frame.assign(new=new)

        A  B  new
0     red  1   10
1   green  2   20
2    blue  1   10
3   green  1   20
4  yellow  2   30
5    blue  1   10
```

This is kind of neat too.  Python 3 only, use `dot` instead of `@` for Python 2

```
a = frame.A.values
red = a == 'red'
blue = a == 'blue'
green = a == 'green'
yellow = a == 'yellow'

new = np.column_stack([red | blue, green, yellow]) @ [10, 20, 30]
frame.assign(new=new)

        A  B  new
0     red  1   10
1   green  2   20
2    blue  1   10
3   green  1   20
4  yellow  2   30
5    blue  1   10
```